# Does anyone know of a complete list of theorems?

Tags: reference-request

It seems like this should exist somewhere but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I am looking for some book or encyclopedia with a list of common mathematical theorems or at least the ones that are common enough to have their own names. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: [The Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s)?

Comment: Anyway, why do you ask? There are infinitely many theorems that can be stated in ZFC. A large number of them are completely uninteresting. So the answer to the question in the title would be: no, no one has written down a complete list of all theorems. It would help enormously if you clarify your question and limit it to some possibly finite list of theorems.

Comment: @russjohnson09 Does my post below answer your queries? If so you can accept it to acknowledge that it does.

Comment: Wasn't that the point of Bourbaki?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try:

(1) [Wikipedia's list of fundamental theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fundamental_theorems)

(2) [Wikipedia's list of lemmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lemmas)

(3) [Wikipedia's list of misnamed theorems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_misnamed_theorems)